# Steps to Make Mogenerator Work in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, mogenerator

I am following the steps in this link: http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/

I have done this before in Xcode 4.6 but now that I have updated to Xcode 5 I couldn't follow it anymore.

I selected my target but I couldn't find the "Add Build Phase” then “Add Run Script”.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the tool bar.
`Editor > Add build phase > Add run script build phase`
Be sure that the target is selected, otherwise the option menu will be disabled.

Step by step with screenshots: http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com/

Comment: Haha. I love that Crashlytics have made that a site.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, for some reason, even after selecting the correct Target, the "Editor \ Add Build Phase \ Add Run Script Build Phase" menu option is disabled.

Instead, you need to make sure "Build Phases" tab is selected for your target, then click on the little "+" button on this page.

[image: Add build script]

XCode 5 is full of quirks like this !